# Nested for loop comprehension + push/pop

Tags: assembly, irvine32

I'm trying to create a procedure that generates a random string of length L, containing all capital letters. This procedure receives the length of the string (L) in EAX, and the pointer to a byte array in ESI where the random string will be saved. Returns the pointer to a byte array in ESI held the random string.

```
;.386
;.model flat,stdcall
;.stack 4096
;ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
;bArray BYTE 100 DUP(0), 0
bArray BYTE ?
count DWORD ?
ranNum DWORD ?

.code
main proc
    call Clrscr
    mov esi, OFFSET bArray
    call Randomize
    mov ecx, 20
    
L1:
    ;call Random32
    mov count, ecx
    mov eax, 100
    call RandomRange
    inc eax
    mov ranNum, eax
    call CreateRandomString
    loop L1

    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp

CreateRandomString PROC
; Receives: Length of the string (L) in EAX, the pointer
; to a byte array in ESI where the random string will be saved
; Returns: Pointer to a byte array in ESI held the random string
;-----------------------------------------------------
mov ecx, ranNum
L2:
    mov eax, 26
    call RandomRange
    add eax, 65
    mov[esi], eax
    call WriteChar
    loop L2
    mov ecx, count
call Crlf
ret
CreateRandomString ENDP

end main
```

This is my code so far and it generates the random length strings, but the loop is infinite when I only want it to iterate 20 times. I know that the 20 I put in ecx gets lost but I'm not sure where in the code that happens and what I should do to change it. I'm thinking something to do with push and pop but I'm still shaky and confused on that concept. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are changing it yourself. `mov ecx, count`. Step through the code in a debugger to see what is happening.

Comment: I have been and I know that it gets changed in the procedure when I write "mov ecx, ranNum", but I'm still confused on the nested for loop

Comment: What about the nested loop is confusing?

Comment: I thought that I'm setting the outer loop to be 20, then the inner loop to be the random number in the procedure. I thought that I needed "mov ecx, count" to restore the outer loop count but I guess I'm not decrementing the number of iterations?

Comment: `mov ecx, count` loads `ecx` from `count`. The value of `count` was set at `mov count, ecx` and not changed thereafter, so the value is always 20.

Comment: When stepping through the debugger, count gets changed from 20 and count and ecx change with the same values which is why I'm lost on what to fix

Comment: Don't use the same register for both loop counters.  The `loop` instruction is slow anyway, just use `dec ebx` / `jnz` or something for one of the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Is it intentional that **you are storing all of the string's characters on top of each other**?
With `bArray BYTE ?` and `mov esi, OFFSET bArray`, later followed by *not* incrementing ESI in the *CreateRandomString* procedure, this is exactly what will happen.

### Why you get an infinite loop

> ```
> bArray BYTE ?
> count DWORD ?
> ```

With *bArray* defined as a mere byte, **you should not be writing a full dword to it**, as in `mov [esi], eax` but rather write `mov [esi], al`. You have effectively destroyed the value 20 that you stored in the *count* variable (that you introduced as a convoluted way to preserve ECX). As a result, the `loop` instruction in the main *L1* loop will always be acting upon ECX=0, looping back indefinitely!

---

> I'm thinking something to do with `push` and `pop`

If you want to use ECX a second time in your *CreateRandomString* procedure, then simply preserve it on the stack:

```
CreateRandomString PROC
    push ecx             ; Preserve ECX
    mov  ecx, ranNum
L2: mov  eax, 26
    call RandomRange     ; -> EAX=[0,25]
    add  eax, 65
    mov  [esi], al       ; Currently storing on top of each other due to
    call WriteChar       ;       lack of `inc esi`, for testing no doubt
    loop L2
    call Crlf
    pop  ecx             ; Restore ECX
    ret
CreateRandomString ENDP
```

As others have suggested, preserving and restoring ECX in the *CreateRandomString* procedure would not be necessary if you would use another counting register in the main *L1* loop. And as a bonus, you will have avoided using [the slow `loop` instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C46.4656):

```
    mov  ebx, 20
L1: mov  eax, 100
    call RandomRange     ; -> EAX=[0,99]
    inc  eax
    mov  ranNum, eax
    call CreateRandomString
    dec  ebx
    jnz  L1
```